# What does ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary really do?

Tags: python, dll, import

I am a little confused with python3, ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary.
Now see the following,I have a file named '_iterative.cpython-36m-x86_64-cygwin.dll',  and I wrote a python script named '_iterative.py' to import it:

```
import ctypes
api = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("_iterative.cpython-36m-x86_64-cygwin.dll")
```

Well the weird part is that when I just typed those command in Python REPL, and list api's `__dir__`, list  current module's `__dir__`, that's different with the case when I use import.
To be more clear, see the pictures:
[using REPL commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Djo.png)

[use import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHiEF.png)

can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because doing `import` means something more than mere load of a dll.
While `LoadLibrary` does exactly that: just load a [binary] lib in a way you *may be able* to call something from there (no warranty).

Hence, with `import` you *may* (if the importee provides) get something (like those `dir()` or `globals()`) other than just a handle.

On the other side, `LoadLibrary` does not oblige you to be pythonic in the library you wanna use.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Comment: By the way, can you provide another example from your computer? I can't just make it happen again, feeling so wired!!

Comment: There are some good examples just in Python basecamp https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

Plus, what I personally did (`libc.prctl(15, pname)` call) is illustrated in these examples: http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/1108/ctypes.CDLL (not my page).

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much!